# How can I fix this Cannot convert error?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

I have this error.

```
javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert false of type class java.lang.String to class com.vocabase.objects.dialog.modules.Module
at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:553)
at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
```

On this code.

```
    <c:forEach items="${param}" var="tmp">
        <c:set var="tab" value="${fn:split(tmp.key,'.')}" />
        <c:set var="start" value="${tab[0]}" />
        <c:set var="type" value="${tab[1]}" />
        <c:set var="language" value="${tab[2]}" />
        <%String type=(String)pageContext.getAttribute("type");
        System.out.println(type);
        pageContext.setAttribute("type", type);%>
        <log:debug>saving ${tab}</log:debug>
        <c:if test="${start=='object'}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${param.onglet=='audition'}">

                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${empty language}">
                            <% if("inputTimeout".equals(type)){%>
                                <!-- inputTimeout -->
                                <c:set target="${answerManage}" property="inputTimeout" value="${tmp.value}" />
                            <%}else if("noInput1Management".equals(type)){%>
                                <!-- noInput1Management -->
                                <c:set target="${answerManage.noInput1}" property="management" value="${model:getPromptManagement(tmp.value)}" />
                            <%}else if("noInput2Management".equals(type)){%>
                                <!-- noInput2Management -->
                                <c:set target="${answerManage.noInput2}" property="management" value="${model:getPromptManagement(tmp.value)}" />
                            <%}else if("noInput3Management".equals(type)){%>
                                <!-- noInput3Management -->
                                <c:set target="${answerManage.noInput3}" property="management" value="${model:getPromptManagement(tmp.value)}" />
                            <%}else if("finalNoInputManagement".equals(type)){%>
                                <!-- finalNoInputManagement -->
                                <c:set target="${answerManage.finalNoInput}" property="management" value="${model:getPromptManagement(tmp.value)}" />
                            <%}else if("whatIsNext".equals(type)){%>
                                <!--  whatIsNextNoInput -->
                                <c:if test="${!(tmp.value=='empty')}">
                                    <c:set var="direction" value="${tmp.value}" />
                                    <c:set var="whatIsNextNoInput" value='<%=DirectionType.valueOf( pageContext.getAttribute("direction").toString())%>' />
                                    <c:set target="${answerManage}" property="whatIsNextNoInput" value="${whatIsNextNoInput}" />
                                </c:if>
                            <%}else if("moduleToCallNoInput".equals(type)){%>
                                <!--  moduleToCallNoInput -->
                                    <c:set var="whatIsNext" value='<%=request.getParameter("object.whatIsNext")%>' />
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${tmp.value!='empty' && whatIsNext=='moduleCall'}">
                                            <c:set var="tmp" value="${fn:split(tmp.value, '.')}" />
                                            <!-- id.type -->
                                            <c:set var="module" value="${model:getModuleByType(tmp[0],tmp[1])}" />
                                            <c:if test="${!empty module}">
                                                <c:set target="${answerManage}" property="moduleToCallNoInput" value="${module }" />
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            <c:set target="${answerManage}" property="moduleToCallNoInput" value='<%=null %>' />
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                            <%}else{%>
                                <!-- repeatNoInput1,2,3 || repeatChoiceNoInput1,2,3 -->
                                <c:set target="${answerManage}" property="${type}">
                                    <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${tmp.value=='on' }">true</c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>false</c:otherwise>
                                    </c:choose>
                                </c:set>
                            <%}%>
                        </c:when>...
```

well the error is on the part of

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${tmp.value=='on' }">true</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>false</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And I don't know how to fix it. The error is on java 8 with tomcat 8.5 and it is an update of project form java 6 with tomcat 6 where it works. I need some ideas please, because I tried in all ways possible but the error is on there.

Thank you,
Vlad.

Comment: Probably this: `model:getModuleByType` expects a module not a String. My advise, check the signature of this method and rename all your `tmp` to something more meaningful.

Comment: Well but it pass from the part of `model:getModuleByType` so I don't think that the problem is from there, because on the last else is the error.

Comment: what is `answerManage` what is the type of `type`? if it's a "Module" then there you go